# For field extensions $K/E/F$, $K/F$ is a radical extension if and only if $K/E$ and $E/F$ is a radical extension.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Definition. E/F is radical extension if there is $F\subset F(\alpha_1)\subset F(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)\subset\cdots\subset F(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n) = E$ such that $\alpha_1^{n_1}\in F$ and $\alpha_i^{n_i}\in F(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_{i-1})$ for $i\geq 2$

> For field extensions $K/E/F$, $K/F$ is a radical extension if and only if $K/E$ and $E/F$ is a radical extension.

If direction is clear. But the only if direction is not clear to me. Why is this true? (The fact that $K/E$ is radical extension is not trivial to me)

Answer (score 1):

$F \subset F(\alpha_1) \subset ... \subset F(\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_n)=K$ with $\alpha_i^{n_i}\in F(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_{i-1})$.

Then you have $E \subset E(\alpha_1) \subset ... \subset E(\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_n)$. But $F \subset E \Rightarrow F(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_{i-1}) \subset E(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_{i-1})$ and so $\alpha_i^{n_i}\in E(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_{i-1})$. For the same reason $K=F(\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_n) \subset E(\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_n)$. But $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n \in K \Rightarrow E(\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_n)=K$. So $K/E$ is radical

Comment: How about $E/F$? Can you do that?

Comment: It's not true in general that $E/F$ is radical. See here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/350776/a-radical-extension-with-a-non-radical-subextension The correct statement of the theorem is: $K/F \ radical \Rightarrow K/E \ radical$. And $K/F \  radical \Leftarrow K/E, E/F \ radical$